# Passing delegate to linq query in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following delegate declaration:

```
private Func<Employee, bool> _exclude;
```

Then elsewhere in my code I set its value to this:

```
_exclude = (subject) =>
  !subject.IsDeleted && subject.Location.Department.Company.GroupId.Equals(_groupId);
```

The objective is to reuse the filter across all queries. This works fine if I'm going to materialize an employee instance like this:

```
Employee theEmployee = db.Employees
    .Include(e=>e.Location)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Department)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Company)
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeId == EmployeeId && _exclude(e))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But it fails when I just wanted to retrieve a single value,like for instance, EmployeeId:

```
string employeeId = db.Employees
    .Include(e=>e.Location)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Department)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Company)
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeId == EmployeeId && _exclude(e))
    .Select(e => e.EmployeeId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The above fails producing a NullReferenceException in the Func delegate *_exclude* because subject.Location value is null, that means the employee passed to the delegate is not full materialized as per Includes.

What can be the cause that it successfully materialize the Employee graph when a full fledged Employee is needed but fails for the projection query, or how should the query be composed in this cases?

I am using EF Core

Comment: check the data, to see the locations of that employee you are passing, I think what is happening is that there is not attached a location for one of your employees

Comment: @Zinov, every employee has a location, it is mandatory field in the backend. Remember that for the full Employee it works great, if not it should fail too.

Comment: Any reason for using `Func<...>` instead of `Expression<Func<...>>`?

Comment: @IvanStoev, actually no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can be the cause that it successfully materialize the Employee graph when a full fledged Employee is needed but fails for the projection query

In both cases the `_exclude(e)` is not translated to SQL, but evaluated in memory, and it fails in the second scenario because of the [Ignored includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) and the lack of lazy loading support.

It's always better to use `Expression<Func<...>>` when possible because they are translated to SQL and evaluated at database side, so includes don't matter.

In your case it's quite easy to change the type of `_exclude` variable (the lambda syntax of assigning it remains the same) and use chained `Where` instead on `&&`:

```
private Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> _exclude;
```

(based on the filter semantics, it should really be called `_include` or `_filter`, but anyway)

and

```
_exclude = (subject) =>
  !subject.IsDeleted && subject.Location.Department.Company.GroupId.Equals(_groupId);
```

Now this works:

```
Employee theEmployee = db.Employees
    .Include(e=>e.Location)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Department)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Company)
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeId == EmployeeId)
    .Where(_exclude)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

as well as this:

```
string employeeId = db.Employees
    // not needed, but will not hurt if used, will be ignored anyway
    //.Include(e=> e.Location)
    //.ThenInclude(e => e.Department)
    //.ThenInclude(e => e.Company)
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeId == EmployeeId)
    .Where(_exclude)
    .Select(e => e.EmployeeId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```